# Configuring NGINX as reverse-proxy (to dispatch) to backend services that are already SSL configured

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have one physical server and one `IP address`. On that server I have three (qty. 3) backend services configured, **each having it's own public DNS domain-name** and **each having it's own `Let's Encrypt SSL certificates`**, as shown:

```
 - svc01.example.com:1443  # Own DNS domain-name and SSL certificates.
 - svc02.example.com:2443  # Own DNS domain-name and SSL certificates.
 - svc03.example.com:3443  # Own DNS domain-name and SSL certificates.
```

These coexist on the same physical server, so each is configured to use it's own `Port`; however the `public IP-Address` for `svc01|02|03.example.com` are identical.

Keeping in mind that these backend services are **already SSL configured** (and I can't undo that), how do I configure `NGINX` to implement the following simple forwards (almost like a dispatcher):

```
 svc01.example.com:443  --> svc01.example.com:1443
 svc02.example.com:443  --> svc02.example.com:2443
 svc03.example.com:443  --> svc03.example.com:3443
```

Sadly, I'm not an `NGINX` person, so a complete configuration file for each would be deeply appreciated:

```
- svc01_nginx.conf
- svc02_nginx.conf
- scv03_nginx.conf
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/kekru/c09dbab5e78bf76402966b13fa72b9d2#non-terminating-tls-pass-through

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you! I took a look and it looks directionally like what I need. :)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich FYI: If you author a complete (cut & paste-able) answer using the server names and scenario in my question, I'll look to upvote it and possibly selecting it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you with the right hint. But feel free to answer this question yourself based on the hint I gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by @SteffenUllrich in the comments above, the solution is shown below. Not being an `nginx` guy, I'm not sure if there are other best-practices to make this configuration more secure or robust (fee free to comment), but it's a start.

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
  
events {}

stream {    
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $targetBackend {
    svc01.example.com svc01.example.com:1443
    svc02.example.com svc02.example.com:2443
    svc03.example.com svc03.example.com:3443    
  }

  server {
    listen 8443;    
    # ==============================================================
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html
    # ==============================================================
    proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
    proxy_timeout 600s;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 8.8.4.4 1.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass $targetBackend;
    # ==============================================================

    # ==============================================================
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html
    # ==============================================================
    ssl_preread on;
    # ==============================================================
  }
}
```

I hope this helps others. (◠﹏◠)